# NodeJs: Upper case a string

Tags: node.js

I want to Upper case a string, I've tried this, but none of them works

```
format.printf((info:any) => `${info.timestamp} ${upperCase(info.level)}: ${info.message}`)
format.printf((info:any) => `${info.timestamp} ${capitalize.words(info.level)}: ${info.message}`)
format.printf((info:any) => `${info.timestamp} ${capitalize(info.level)}: ${info.message}`)
```

Comment: [string.toUppercase()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) should work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use JavaScript built-in function `toUpperCase()`.

Something like below.

```js
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.toUpperCase();

console.log(res) // "HELLO WORLD!"
```

Official guide: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp